# Trigger a Custom Method When Next Day Begins

Tags: ios

How can I trigger a custom method only when the next day begins? In other words if today is October 12, 2013 then I want to trigger the method on October 13, 2013 OR October 12 2013 midnight?

Comment: Assuming the app is still active? What have you tried?

Comment: Use a `NSTimer` (only if the app stays open), or schedule a local notification (if the app is closed).

Comment: The app will be suspended (in background mode).

Comment: I thought about local notification but does local notification allows for called a custom method.

Comment: Local notifications are able to trigger a method as long as the user has tapped on the banner. The delegate function `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` is called.

Comment: There will be no banner or alerts! I just want to refresh the user's view when the next day begins.